# Detect traffic loss between OS and NGINX

Tags: nginx, http, linux-networking

I have a analytics-tracking linux server (Ubuntu on EC2) running NGINX & Redis (this project - https://github.com/FTBpro/count-von-count)

When I go over the NGINX logs, I see that the traffic is 30% lower compared to other metrics that I have, and the NGINX error log doesn't show anything suspicious.

My guess is that, at traffic peeks, the server/machine is just not able to handle all the incoming traffic.
I though about tweaking the machine & NGINX for better performance, but before doing so, I want to validate my theory,

so I was wondering:

1) Is there a way to see if some traffic is "dropped" between the OS and the NGINX (i.e. the machine can handle the incoming traffic but the NGINX is too busy) ?

2) Is there a way to see if the machine itself can't handle all the traffic?

Thanks.

-------------------------- Conclusions so far ---------------------------
1) This [blog post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-nginx/) explains pretty nicely about NGINX monitoring. Basically it uses the stub-module which [Seva Kobylin](https://serverfault.com/users/305575/seva-kobylin) recommended on in his answer. I also started the free trial with DataDogHQ, and it gives a really nice simple solution for monitoring and visualizing.
2) Unfortunately the above still doesn't answer my second question, but at least I have some visibility on the first part, so thats something :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Stub-module -- see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html
2. `netstat -s`

Comment: If I understand correctly this shows me the status in real time. Since I don't know when the traffic peaks will happen I'd love a way to look at it retrospective (maybe have it saved in some log file or something...)               Also, what exactly can i learn from the stub-module? I don't mind having waiting connections as long as they get handled eventually, But I want to know if some connections never even get to the NGINX level.

Comment: You can draw graphics by this module (see graphit for example).